# Django extended template not displaying content

Tags: django, django-templates

There have been a few other threads about this topic, but specifically one with an answer of a urls.py issue didn't resolve mine...

I'm attempting to extend a base template. I have two files, base.html and index.html. Base has basic navigational elements, CSS, etc., and index.html extends base. I'm pointing to index.html in my view, but all I can see is code from base.html -- the index.html code is not displaying. Any help is appreciated. Also, there are no errors reported anywhere for any of this code.

**views.py:**

```
class DashboardView(TemplateView):

    context_object_name = 'home_list'
    template_name = 'index.html'
    queryset = Media.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['jobs'] = Job.objects.all()
        return context
```

Relevant portions of **urls.py:**

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^apiroot/', router.get_api_root_view()),
url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
url(r'^$', dashboard_views.DashboardView.as_view(), name="home_list"),
```

**base.html** in the templates dir: (Note that the "Test." part of this does show up on the screen, but that is the last element on the page when loaded.)

```
{# load the tag library #}
{% load bootstrap3 %}

{% load staticfiles %}

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="{{STATIC_URL}}bootstrap3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

{# load CSS and Javascript #}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as bootstrap alerts #}
{% bootstrap_messages %}

<div class = "container">
Backup Administraton  (test)
</div>

<!------Navbar ---------->

<header class = "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role = "banner">
<div class = "container">
    <div class ="navbar-header">
        <button type = "button" class= "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = "#dropdown">
            <span class = "sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <a href="/" class ="navbar-brand">Backup Administration</a>
    </div><!-- End Navbar Header-->

    <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id = "dropdown">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right" role = "navigation">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reports</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Snapshots</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Restores</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- End Nav Contents -->
</div><!-- End Container -->
</header>



Test.
```

Contents of **index.html**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
<BR><BR><BR><BR>

Testing contents of index.html

{% block content %}
<BR><BR><BR><BR><BR>
This is index.html<BR>

{% endblock %}
```

The index.html contents (ie the "Testing contents") never displays on the screen. FWIW, the BR's were to make sure the text didn't display behind the black nav bar.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add a content block to your `base.html`, for example:

```
...
<div class = "container">
Backup Administraton  (test)
</div>
<div class="container">
{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</div>
<!------Navbar ---------->
...
```

Comment: I added exactly what you suggested, and received:
NoReverseMatch at /

Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: That's a separate issue. Somewhere in your code you are using `reverse('index')` or in your templates you are using `{% url 'index' %}`. However, this does not match the pattern in your urls, which is `home_list`. You must change one or the other, so that they match.

Comment: Wow -- been staring at this code for so long I glossed right over it. That was it, thanks so much! Can you explain why the block/endblock is required for the template to show up? I couldn't find anything like that in the template docs specifically.

Comment: It's the way that [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance) works. The parent template defines blocks that the child templates can override. The child template does not need to override all of the parent templates. If a block is defined in the child template but not the parent template, it has no effect.

Comment: Great explanation.. thanks... I had it completely backwards about how the extension happened. Definitely explains a lot.